# Getting value from text box in SAP application custom container

Tags: autoit, sap-gui

My requirement is to automate SAP flow using AutoIt. When I am trying to get the values(test) from below username textbox it is not getting the text box value and displaying an empty value. I want to get the value from the text box and I need to compare with string. Could you please help me out?

[image]

Output :

[image]

I already referred below links :

- https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlGetText.html
- https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/177533-get-text-from-a-button/
- https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/116065-get-text-from-active-window/

A screenshot of AutoIt finder tool :

[image]

My AutoIt code :

```
Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe")
Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive("SAP Logon 740")

WinSetState($hWnd, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)

ControlFocus("SAP Logon 740","","SAPTreeList1")
ControlTreeView("SAP Logon 740","","[CLASS:SAPTreeList; INSTANCE:1]","Expand","#0")
ControlClick("SAP Logon 740","","[CLASS:SAPTreeList; INSTANCE:1]","left",2,47,60)
Sleep(2000)
ControlClick("SAP Logon 740","","[CLASS:SAPTreeList; INSTANCE:1]","left",2,59,115)
Sleep(2000)
ControlClick("SAP Logon 740","","[CLASS:SysListView32; INSTANCE:1]","left",1,71,573)

Sleep(1000)
ControlClick("SAP Logon 740","","Log &On")
Sleep(3000)
Local $hNewWnd = WinWaitActive("SAP")
; Retrieve the classlist of the Notepad window using the handle returned by WinWait.
    Local $sClassList = WinGetClassList("SAP")
#ConsoleWrite($sClassList)
    ; Display the classlist.
Sleep(3000)
ControlClick("SAP","","","left",1,179,56)
    # MsgBox(0, "output", $sClassList)
Send("test")
Sleep(1000)
$wrd = ControlGetText("SAP","test","")
MsgBox(0,"Display",$wrd)
```

Control tab :

[image]

Comment: You got it all wrong. Show me the "Control" tab from window info tool when you focus that username edit box.

Comment: Thanks @Milos for your comment.Please find the screenshot of "Control Tab" .Class: Afx:68570000:1008
Instance: 1
ClassnameNN: Afx:68570000:10081
Name: 
Advanced (Class): [CLASS:Afx:68570000:1008; INSTANCE:1]
ID: 100
Text: 
Position: 0, 104
Size: 1510, 653
ControlClick Coords: 192, 56
Style: 0x56000000
ExStyle: 0x00000010
Handle: 0x00020256

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [this](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/controls.htm) and [this](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm).

```
#RequireAdmin ;sometimes this is required in order to be able to manipulate windows
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also

$wrd = ControlGetText("[TITLE:SAP]","",100);100 is id from the WindowInfo Tool
If @error Then $wrd = ControlGetText("[TITLE:SAP]","","[CLASS:Afx:68570000:1008; INSTANCE: 1]")
;This is the advanced method. Aslo shown in the WIndowInfo Tool.
MsgBox(0,"Display",$wrd)
```

Comment: Thanks @Milos . I tried this above code but still i am unable to retirve the test value .. Could you please explain how above code is related to getting the value from the text field in SAP customer container  ?  ..... AutoIT v3 Window Info option is not focusing particular filed and it is focusing the frame .. could you please help us with more details.. please refer my above code